# Entity Framework 5 Nuget Console commands

Tags: entity-framework, command-line, nuget, entity-framework-migrations

So I am making a DB with EF 5 Code first, I have checked some guides and found some "important"/useful commands like: "Update-Database -Force -Verbose". However I know there must be more commands like these, something like: "Purge-Database", but no success in finding them. So my question is, where can I find all the availible commands and flags(for example: -Force, -Verbose etc) for EF 5.

I tried google but no luck, since query "EF 5 Console" etc has console and it gives result about console applications, which I don t want ofc.

Comment: Excellent question. This needs to be added as a summary in the MSDN.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just use:

```
get-help EntityFramework
```

to get list of supported commands and:

```
get-help Update-Database
```

to get help for a queried command. Help for each command can give you information about extended help by for example using:

```
get-help Update-Database -detailed
```

You will probably be disappointed because there are only four commands provided by EF.

Comment: And there's a handy summary page [here](https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/).

Comment: Unfortunately `Get-Help EntityFramework` doesn't work for me (in VS2017) - it can't find EntityFramework in help files. Even `Update-Help` doesn't help.

Comment: As I have noticed (all works for me in VS2015) `get-help EntityFramework` returns contents of file `<Project>\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\about_EntityFramework.help.txt`.